# Heroku app working, but won't allow me to push additional changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I have a heroku app with two remotes: staging and production. So far I've had no issues with this.

Today I have successfully pushed to my production app, but get the following error when trying to push/fetch my staging app.

```
 !  Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
 !  See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
 !  If the problem persists, please contact http://support.heroku.com.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The staging app is working properly. It responds to requests and I can do things like `heroku run console --remote=staging` successfully.

I tried `git push -f staging master` and got the same error. All of my heroku apps are running, but for some reason I can't push to this staging app.

Here's what I get when I run `heroku run rake about --remote=staging`

```
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.2 (x86_64-linux)
RubyGems version          1.3.7
Rack version              1.4
Rails version             3.2.8
Active Record version     3.2.8
Action Pack version       3.2.8
Active Resource version   3.2.8
Action Mailer version     3.2.8
Active Support version    3.2.8
Middleware                Rack::Cache, ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, Rack::Auth::Basic, #<ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware:0x00000003adf3b0>, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport, Warden::Manager
Application root          /app
Environment               staging
Database schema version   20120922013103
```

Comment: Same thing for me, but has been like this for 24 hours. Strange because I can push to another app...

Comment: I just heard from Heroku. I was able to push to some repos and not others. They claim the repo got corrupted on their end. The reset the cache and now it's working again ... but I had to wait 6 days, which was definitely not cool.